# throw new MongoParseError(err.message);

Tags: node.js

**After run server ,show this error on terminal.**

```
   MongoParseError: URI malformed
    at new ConnectionString (D:\MERN Project\Train Project\Backend\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:102:23)
    at parseOptions (D:\MERN Project\Train Project\Backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:209:17)
    at new MongoClient (D:\MERN Project\Train Project\Backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:65:63)
    at D:\MERN Project\Train Project\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:801:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\MERN Project\Train Project\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:798:19)
    at D:\MERN Project\Train Project\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:381:10
    at D:\MERN Project\Train Project\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (D:\MERN Project\Train Project\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
```

**Server.js**

```
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const cors=require('cors');
const app=express();
require("dotenv").config();

const PORT=process.env.PORT || 8070;
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyparser.json());

const URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect(URL);

try{
const connection=mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open",() => {
    console.log("Monogodb connection successfull");
});
}catch(e){
    console.log("error:"(e));
}

function close_connection(){
    connection.close();
}

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("Server is up and running on port number:"+PORT)
    
});
```

Comment: The error message points to where you should look for the issue! `URI malformed at new ConnectionString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue as this -> I was added '%,$' to my cluster password. After removed them mongodb connection was succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in this question was caused by having a special character in the password like "@".

in order to use @ as part of the password, the following can be done by replacing @ with %40 which is the hex representation in ASCII for the @ symbol.

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://username:p%40ssword@host:port/dbname?authSource=admin", { 
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }, function(err, db) {

    }
);
```

Comment: .env file hasn't any problem.i checked.also code hasn't any problem.  @Edtimer

Comment: hey @SahiruLakshan, have you tried copying the variable in env to replace const URL = value to check?

Comment: yes.but not work @Edtimer

Comment: would you share the mongo url here after obfuscating the password

Comment: mongodb+srv://Sahiru:XXXXXX@trainproject.lll3skr.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority  @Edtimer

Comment: `console.log (URL)` and check if it shows a value or is it undefined

Comment: show the value @Edtimer

Comment: try to connect to the database in the way I specified as an answer to your question above. i believe there is a syntax error in the way you are connecting. remove `mongoose.connect(URL);

try{
const connection=mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open",() => {
    console.log("Monogodb connection successfull");
});
}catch(e){
    console.log("error:"(e));
}

function close_connection(){
    connection.close();
}` and replace it with the snippet I supplied

Comment: I fixed the error.that error had been in mongodb password.My password had '@,#' symbols.After remove them mongodb connection was succeed.Thank for ur responses.

Comment: nicely done @SahiruLakshan. will up date the answer above to include this possibility.upvoting it will help other users facing similar issues.